# Do compiler warnings add to the build time?

Tags: .net, performance, msbuild

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a huge amount of warnings make C# compile time longer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168433/does-a-huge-amount-of-warnings-make-c-compile-time-longer)

In MSBuild / Visual Studio, if your code generates a lot of FXCop or StyleCop warnings, does this have a performance impact on the build time?

Comment: Build time  should be your least concern when you get many warnings.

Comment: Build time should be your least concern anyway. It's runtime performance what really matters.

Comment: @WTP: Well, lower build time makes the write-compile-debug-cycle go faster, ultimately increasing productivity, so it *is* an advantage. Of course, just like squeezing a 1% speedup out of initialization code is pointless, shaving 1 second off a build that takes several minutes helps noone.

Comment: @delnan If you have a build time of several minutes you either build for the first time, don't test enough or you recompile everything over and over again. Good compilers will keep the compiled code and only recompile what has changed. I have projects with over five hundred source files, when I change one file the total compile time is about a second. Though I do agree with you. (note: I have never worked with Visual Studio, only GCC and LLVM.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the warnings that will add to the build time, it's the static analysis tools that you are using that will slow down, no matter whether the code is valid or not.